# Can my forms' questions be modified automatically according to previous users answers?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to create a Google forms that will help me to track problems at work. Employees would fill the form if they experience any problem at a specific station. I do not want problems to be reported more than once.

So let's say `employee 1` fill the form to tell me there is a problem at station `4` and the next day `employee 2` realises the same problem at station `4`. I would like him to see within the Google Forms that the problem has already been submitted.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I've searched on Google and found nothing. I don't have any background in computer science at all. Thank you, you've been helpful!

Comment: Welcome That's a complex system. 1) the form with error reporting fields (type and location?); 2) form submission-,recognise the error, and copies it to a log; 3) log shows open jobs; 4) the log is accessible along with the form. Can it be done? Certainly. Is there an-off-the-shelf-system for this? No. I suggest you start off by designing a form, including details of the types and locations of errors that people might report. Then you can link the form submission to a spreadsheet and think about detecting new errors, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to create a form that sends the results to a spreadsheet. I embedded both the form and the spreadsheet on a website, so people can see what's been submitted already. Not the ideal solution, but it'll work just fine. Thank you for your help!